# change designated name of encrypted lvm root? from sdo to sdn in crypttab?

Tags: debian, luks, cryptsetup, dm-crypt, crypttab

I installed debian stretch using encrypted lvm from the installer on a usb drive.

during installation, with all disks connected, `sdo5` is assigned to my boot disk. when running the full system, my boot disk is now assigned `sdn5`

this is problematic, because I have an encrypted data disk that shows up as sdo1, as per `blkid`.

I need to change the crypt configuration and initramfs to look for sdn, so that sdo is free. how can I do that?

simply changing the crypttab and running `update-initramfs -u -k all` gives an error about invalid line in crypttab and then the system will not boot.

`cryptsetup: WARNING: invalid line in /etc/crypttab for sdo5_crypt`

there must be another step. where is sdo5_crypt referenced other than `crypttab`?

my `crypttab` is as follows:

`sdo5_crypt UUID=long_string_here none luks`

and my `fstab` is:

```
/dev/mapper/coldstorage--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sdo1 during installation
UUID=long_string_here /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/coldstorage--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

EDIT:

I can see there is a lingering /dev/mapper/sdo5_crypt even when I reboot after changing `crypttab` but not updating initramfs (which causes the system to request the password for `sdn5`)

If I can rename that, it might be enough? `lvrename` does not seem to work.

```
# ls /dev/mapper/
control  sdo5_crypt  coldstorage--vg-root  coldstorage--vg-swap_1
```

result of `pvdisplay`

```
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/mapper/sdo5_crypt
  VG Name               coldstorage-vg
```

and attempt to fix...
    # pvmove /dev/mapper/sdo5_crypt /dev/mapper/sdn5_crypt
      Physical Volume "/dev/mapper/sdn5_crypt" not found in Volume Group "coldstorage-vg".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it.

```
dmsetup rename sdo5_crypt sdn5_crypt
sed -i -e 's/sdo5_crypt/sdn5_crypt/g' /etc/crypttab
update-initramfs -u -k all
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for posting these instructions. I was curious why `dmsetup rename` was necessary. Now I know the reason: When you `update-initramfs`, it will look on your system for a mounted device mapper named whatever new name you gave it. That's why the steps are as you say: 1. Rename the mapper device on your live system, 2. Edit crypttab to refer to the device as its new name, 3. Update initramfs to install the new crypttab settings into your boot system. Makes perfect sense! Your list is the exact list of necessary commands! Although I use `vi /etc/crypttab` to edit it manually. :-)